# Does the War Department building effect stack with Scythia's trait?

Tags: civilization-6-rise-and-fall

They both give a bonus to HP on kill, do they stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They **do** stack. I just tested with the September 2019 Update, killing a unit and healing 44 hp to full.